# How to remove an android virtual device that is not in the list?

Tags: virtual, device

When I try to emulate something it always displays this emulator info, I don't know where it comes from
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA5qL.png)

However, when I go to the device manager it only displays 1
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue0Lg.png)

When I give `flutter emulators` command I have this return
[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX1l3.png)

I have no idea how to remove

I can't find any commands or any way to solve it.